# Unable to publish a gradle Jar artifact to a sonatype repository

Tags: maven, gradle, sonatype

I am following instructions in the [Sonatype](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-gradle/) documentation for publishing a gradle project.

I have the following gradle version.

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-11-25 13:35:10 UTC
Revision:     daece9dbc5b79370cc8e4fd6fe4b2cd400e150a8

Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

When I try to use the `uploadArchives`  task as given in their example, I get the following error:

```
$ ./gradlew uploadArchives

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/ferozed/stash/libs/mask-json-field-transform/build.gradle' line: 167

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mask-json-field-transform'.
> Could not find method uploadArchives() for arguments [build_6yphclnk6m8p3rtmq5h7m56li$_run_closure12@19fbeecd] on root project 'mask-json-field-transform' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:7.1.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java' // so that we can use 'implementation', 'testImplementation' for dependencies
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'signing'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
    }
    maven {
        url = "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

group = 'io.github.ferozed.kafka.connect'
version = '0.1'

dependencies {

    // Kafka
    implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'connect-api', version: '3.3.1'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect:connect-utils:0.7.173'
    implementation 'com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect:kafka-connect-transform-common:0.1.0.14'

    //test
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.0'))
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.2")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
        }

        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/avro", "src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}


task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

tasks.withType(AbstractArchiveTask).configureEach {
    preserveFileTimestamps = false
    reproducibleFileOrder = true
}

plugins.withId("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"){

    //this block requires the java plugin to be applied first.
    plugins.withId("java"){

        shadowJar {
            //We are overriding the default jar to be the shadow jar
            classifier = null
            exclude 'META-INF'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.INF'
            exclude 'META-INF/license/*'
        }

        jar {
            manifest {
                attributes(
                        'Built-By'       : System.properties['user.name'],
                        'Build-Timestamp': new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(new Date()),
                        'Created-By'     : "Gradle ${gradle.gradleVersion}",
                        'Build-Jdk'      : "${System.properties['java.version']} (${System.properties['java.vendor']} ${System.properties['java.vm.version']})",
                        'Build-OS'       : "${System.properties['os.name']} ${System.properties['os.arch']} ${System.properties['os.version']}"
                )
            }
        }

        tasks.build.dependsOn tasks.shadowJar
        tasks.shadowJar.mustRunAfter tasks.jar
        tasks.shadowJar.mustRunAfter tasks.javadocJar
        tasks.shadowJar.mustRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar

    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            pom {
                name = 'Mask Json Field Transform'
                description = 'A kafka connect transform to remove the value of a sensitive field in a json document.'
                url = 'https://github.com/ferozed/mask-json-field-transform'
                properties = [
                        myProp: "value",
                        "prop.with.dots": "anotherValue"
                ]
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                        url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id = 'ferozes'
                        name = 'Feroze Daud'
                        email = 'ferozed.oss@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection = 'scm:git:git@github.com:ferozed/mask-json-field-transform.git'
                    developerConnection = 'scm:git:git@github.com:ferozed/mask-json-field-transform.git'
                    url = 'https://github.com/ferozed/mask-json-field-transform'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign configurations.archives
    sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
}

tasks.signArchives.dependsOn tasks.shadowJar

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar, sourcesJar
}


uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            beforeDeployment { deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

            repository(url: "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
                authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
            }

            snapshotRepository(url: "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
                authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
            }

            pom.project {
                name 'Example Application'
                packaging 'jar'
                // optionally artifactId can be defined here
                description 'A kafka connect transform to remove the value of a sensitive field in a json document.'
                url 'https://github.com/ferozed/mask-json-field-transform'

                scm {
                    connection 'scm:svn:http://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/'
                    developerConnection 'scm:svn:https://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/'
                    url 'https://github.com/ferozed/mask-json-field-transform'
                }

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }

                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'ferozed'
                        name 'Feroze Daud'
                        email 'feroz@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you may not need to 'fix the error' so to speak, in that it appears the problematic code MAY be able to be outright deleted.  However...

To fix the error...

```
 Could not find method uploadArchives() for arguments [build_6yphclnk6m8p3rtmq5h7m56li$_run_closure12@19fbeecd] on root project 'mask-json-field-transform' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

This is telling us that uploadArchives is not valid.  See immediately below.

I believe you may need to use the maven plugin to access this functionality.
https://github.com/siddeshbg/gradle-uploadArchives/blob/master/README.md

to do this, add:

```
   id 'maven'
```

to your plugins{}
block.

The above example explains that the maven plugin is responsible for doing this

> ```
> The Maven plugin adds support for deploying artifacts to Maven repositories
> ```

It is worth considering also that the author of the above repository claims:

> This is the legacy publishing mechanism, should not be used in newer
> builds

Now... on to the better solution, forgetting the maven plugin, in favor of the maven-publish plugin you're already using...

I do not personally work with Maven often enough to know what other mechanisms one should use, but Google suggests that perhaps the maven-publish plugin you're using might do this WITHOUT the 'uploadArchives{}' portion of your code that is causing the error.

See:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

Per this page, it would seem the entire uploadArchives block is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the `maven` plugin. But my build cant find it.

I am using `gradle 7` and `maven` plugin does not work with it.

Comment: Also... there are two things happening here: 1) Need to generate the maven POM, and sign it. 2) Need to upload the whole jar + pom to artifactory. It is #2 i am having problems with.

Comment: The reason for the `uploadArchives` section is that we dont want that to happen everytime. Only when the user absolutely wants to publish to maven central. Having it that way allows to run `gradle uploadArchives`

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_customization.html#sec:publishing_custom_artifacts_to_maven

https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/publishing/

It would appear that you generate a shadow jar.  If you combine the literature in the first link... with the literature in the second link... I think it might be enough.  Still heavily leaning against needing the uploadArchives... this is a feature of the maven plugin from everything that I can see.  So without the maven plugin, I cannot see that block working as intended.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenArtifact.html

This link might be useful too